# TreeSet not adding all elements and HashSet

Tags: java

I have two sets on my code, and on them I add the same collection of elements. The problem is, the TreeSet doesn't add all elements. I am getting a bit confused.

I having a problem for a while now and I am struggling to find out why my TreeSet won’t add all of the elements in the Collection I pass to addAll.

It is a TreeSet build with a comparator, for items that have an equals method like:

```
public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this==o;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 67 * hash +     Objects.hashCode(this.grauDeAdaptacao);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.idade);
    return hash;
}
```

Just to test I did the following:

```
HashSet<Item> test1 = new HashSet<>(items);
TreeSet<Item> test2 = new TreeSet<>(getComparator());
test2.addAll(items);
if (test1.size() < 50 || test2.size()<50 ) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

And the comparator uses:

```
private int compare(S ser1, S ser2) {
    return ser1.getGrau().compareTo(ser2.getGrau());
}
```

But what is awkward is that, the hash seams fine, while the TreeSet don’t have all 50 elements.

I need two elements to be equal just when they are the same instance, in all subclasses, that is why I made the final method like that.

Comment: Why does your comparator not use its inputs? Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: And why are you overriding `equals` but not changing the behaviour... whereas you *are* changing the behaviour of `hashCode()`? Basically it's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: it uses, am sorry..just a sec

Comment: Your `equals` method is almost certainly not compatible with your `compareTo`, which `TreeSet` requires: "Note that the ordering ... must be consistent with equals..." In other words, iff two objects are equal, comparing them should result in 0.

Comment: equals and hashCode implementations don't follow Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" chapter 3 recommendations.  I would encourage you to read it.

Comment: I need the behavior in all sub classes, that is why I out equals there, and made it final.

Comment: HashSet and TreeSet don't contain duplicates. Maybe you add duplicate elements?

Comment: but the hashSet gets 50 and the tree 49

Comment: `TreeSet` uses `compareTo` to determine equality. Maybe by compareTo your two instance are equal. Can you show what is in  `ser1.getGrau().compareTo(ser1.getGrau());`

Comment: Did you copy-paste code correctly? If so, you probably have a bug in your comparison method - the second use of `ser1` should be `ser2`.

Comment: it is just two Doubles

Comment: it was just a typo here..I corrected it now

Comment: Maybe you have `Double.NaN` which is considered equal by `compareTo` method. Check that all values returned by `getGrau()` are numerical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashSet` uses `equals` to test two objects for equality.

A `HashSet` guarantees that it is never the case that for any two distinct objects, `a` and `b`, in the `Set` `a.equals(b) == true`.

A `TreeSet` uses `compareTo` to test two objects for equality.

A `TreeSet` guarantees that it is never the case that for any two distinct objects, `a` and `b`, in the `Set` `a.compareTo(b) == 0`.

Under the assumption that `a.compareTo(b) == 0` **iff** `a.equals(b)` then this behaviour is the same. Under this condition it can be said that the `compareTo` method is "consistent with `equals`", as defined in the [documentation for `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

The same documentation also states that:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets
>   (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when
>   they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted
>   map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined
>   in terms of the equals method.

This is an example of 'behav[ing] "strangely"'.

You have some objects for which `a.equals(b) == false` **but** `a.compareTo(b) == 0`.

It should further be noted that the for the implementation of `hashCode` it is **required** that if `a.equals(b) == true` then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. This is **not the case** in your implementation. Your implementation of `hashCode()` is invalid given your implementation of `equals`.

The reflexive property is **not** required. i.e. it can (and will) be the case that `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` and `a.equals(b) == false`.

So, in summary.

1. Your `hashCode` and `equals` are wrong. They need to be consistent, as described in the documentation for [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).
2. Your `comapreTo` is wrong, it should be "consistent with `equals`" as described in the [documentation for `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: I love when I get into the "behave "strangely" category..=)

Comment: But now I have an awkward situation because the comparator is supposed to order the elements by the 'grau' property. But they should not be considered equals.

Comment: Well then do not use a `Set`, use `Collections.sort` which produces a stable sort of a `List`. A `Set` guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: I supposed you are right. I was using set to be sure no elements gets in there twice, and it needs to be sorted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, with your help of course.
As I needed a data structure that as efficient to insert and search, while it would be always sorted - beening from the Java SE API. TreeSet was just too simple to not use it. So I adjusted the comparator and the items to use IDs. and just like that the Tree got happy, it ordered my elements with the property I intended, and in case they were the same, the ID would decide the order...it got compatible with equals, and everybody got happy.