# Java TreeSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sorted by the value of the Pair element, how to insert a new pair that has the same value as an existing pair?

Tags: java, key-value, comparator, treeset

I currently have a TreeSet that contains elements of type Pair, and I'm sorting them by their value in descending order.

Here is the link to the original Pair class documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/util/Pair.html

This is the declaration:

```
TreeSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>((a,b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue());
```

My issue is that if I try to insert a few pairs into the set, for example: Pair(4, 51), Pair(8, 85), Pair(1, 16), Pair(2,51), the Pair(2,51) doesn't get inserted.

Code for inserting the pairs:

```
sortedSet.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(4, 51));
sortedSet.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(8, 85));
sortedSet.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 16));
sortedSet.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(2, 51));
```

I managed to figure out that the reason is because there already exists a pair element with the same value - P(4,51), however, they have different keys so they are different elements, and I expected the Pair(2,51) to be inserted before or after P(4,51).

Is there a way I can solve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and share the code of class `Pair`.

Comment: Added the link to the class documentation.

Comment: What do you get for  `new Pair<Integer,Integer> (2,51).hashCode()` and  `new Pair <Integer,Integer> (4,51).hashCode()` ?

Comment: @Catalina You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123336/why-does-my-treeset-not-add-anything-beyond-the-first-element since your comparator say that `(2,51)` and `(4,51)` are the same. Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975154/java-treeset-not-adding-object or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656874/treeset-not-adding-all-elements-and-hashset

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Pair(2,51) hashcode = 6840 and Pair(4,51) hashcode = 6902

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by the definition of the `Comparator`:

```
(a,b) -> b.getValue() - a.getValue()
```

According to this `Comparator`, two `Pair`s with the same `value` are "equal". As to the [contract of `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#add(E)), this means that an `add(...)` adds an element to the `Set` if and only if no element that is "equal" (with respect to the `Comparator`) exists in the `Set`.

If we want to store two `Pair`s with the same `value`, but different `key`s, we need to extend the `Comparator`, such that it returns a non-`0` value for `Pair`s with equal `value`, but different `key`s.

One possibility is to:

- first sort by `value` (descending - as in the original code), and
- then by `key` (either ascending or descending)

The following code accomplishes exactly this. The `.reversed()` is for the descending sort order for `value`, and I chose an ascending sort order for `key`:

```
final TreeSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator
    .comparingInt(Pair<Integer, Integer>::getValue).reversed()
    .thenComparing(Pair::getKey));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qT1DCJ)

Answer (score 0):

A `Set` can not contain duplicates. Instead, you may want to use a `List` and use `Collections.sort()` on it after you're done inserting.

Comment: I understand that a `Set` can not contain duplicates, but I thought I was solving this issue by inserting Pairs with key and value into the set and not only values.